# What is n (Natural number) if the function has to have a limit not equal to zero or infinite?

Tags: limits, functions

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\tan(x))^n - x^n}{x^6}$$

What is n (Natural number) if the function has to have a limit not equal to zero or infinite?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to write its Khayyam-Newton expansion.

Comment: Clearly if you know that $(\tan x - x)/x^{3} \to 1/3$ as $x \to 0$ then you know that the answer is $n = 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Taylor series for $\tan(x)$ you get:

$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3} +O(x^5)$

$\tan^n(x)=(x+\frac{x^3}{3} +O(x^5))^n=x^n+\frac{n}{3}x^{n+2}+O(x^{n+4})$

This means that you can write your limit as:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{n}{3}\frac{x^{n+2}}{x^6}$$

If you want this limit to be a number you need to have $n+2 = 6$, thus $n=4$

Comment: Yeah I fixed that, it should be right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan 0 = 0$, so use Maclaurin series expansion around 0 ( a couple of largest terms will do) and try plugging in values for $n$. What's the smallest one that gives you the result?

Comment: It seems not to be a systematic solution, At least Hopital's rule or equivalence sounds faster and easier. but I debt in the answer.

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari It's not systematic, but the answer clearly won't work with only the linear order term, and it *does* work with the cubic order term, so it seems like it's adequate for this question alone. I do agree that checking values of $n$ is probably harder than just two-term binomial expanding for general $n$.